# How to rewrite into json file nodejs?

Tags: node.js

I have a site where the user can add posts.

I'm trying to add the details of each post request to the `data.json` file.

Every time the user adds a post, I want to write all the posts (new) again into the `data.json` file, but now just the last post is written without all the previous posts.

Any idea?

```
const posts = {};

app.post("/posts", (req, res) => {
const id = randomBytes(4).toString("hex");

var dt = new Date().toLocaleDateString("en-US");

const { title } = req.body;
const { postBody } = req.body;

posts[id] = {
id,
title,
postBody,
dt,
};

console.log(posts);

fs.writeFile('data.json', JSON.stringify(posts, null, 2), function (err) {
 if (err) throw err;
 console.log('Saved!');
});


res.status(201).send(posts[id]);

});
```

For example, instead of

```
{
 '63ca17ec': { id: '63ca17ec', title: 'cd', postBody: '', dt: '12/1/2020' },
 '7a680f01': { id: '7a680f01', title: 'dc', postBody: '', dt: '12/1/2020' }
}
```

I get

```
{
 '63ca17ec': { id: '63ca17ec', title: 'cd', postBody: '', dt: '12/1/2020' }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are overriding the the content of the file you need to read the file first append the new post and save the file.

```
 let posts = {};

  app.post("/posts", (req, res) => {
    const id = randomBytes(4).toString("hex");

    var dt = new Date().toLocaleDateString("en-US");

    const {
        title
    } = req.body;
    const {
        postBody
    } = req.body;

    posts[id] = {
        id,
        title,
        postBody,
        dt,
    };

    try {
        posts = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync('data.json', 'utf8'))
    } catch (e) {
        console.log(e)
    }
    console.log(posts)
    fs.writeFile('data.json', JSON.stringify(posts, null, 2), function(err) {
        if (err) throw err;
        console.log('Saved!');
    });


    res.status(201).send(posts[id]);

  });
```

Comment: thanks but thats what I got "\"\\\"\\\\\\\"\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\". what can be the problem?

Comment: I made a mistake  posts = fs.readFileSync('data.json', 'utf-8')  should be  posts = fs.readFileSync('data.json', 'utf8')  .  the  utf8 should not have a dash

Comment: Now it returns the same but shorter

Comment: `"{\n  \"4e7c14c9\": {\n    \"id\": \"4e7c14c9\",\n    \"title\": \"ds\",\n    \"postBody\": \"\",\n    \"dt\": \"12/1/2020\"\n  }\n}"` . do you have any idea why thats what written?

Comment: the file is not parsed  it should be  posts =JSON.parse (fs.readFileSync('data.json', 'utf8'))

Comment: ok its getting better but when I add a new post the file dosnt change, always return the first post request. Any idea why?

Answer (score 0):

You need to

1. Open `data.json` for read+write.
2. Read the contents of `data.json`.
3. Convert that into a javascript object/array via `JSON.parse()`.
4. add the data item to that object/array.
5. Finally, use `fs.write()` to write to the file at offset +0 (start of file).
6. Close the file.

Comment: const datafile = require("./data.json");
    var as = JSON.parse(datafile);
    fs.write(as,JSON.stringify(posts, null, 2)); thats ok?

Comment: Sure... but `require()` caches the file that it loads. So for the duration your app is running, every time you `require('data.json')`, you will get the same value — whatever data that file held when the app launched.